# Why is there no /group/<groupname> directory?

Tags: filesystems, group

Would it be beneficial to have a directory structure analogous to `/home/<username>` for groups?  `/group/<groupname>`.  The individual group directories would be owned by the group and inaccessible (by default) to users which are not members.  This would be a logical place for groups to share files which other group members may need.

For instance let's take user `pi` (I'm using debian if that isn't obvious) and the group `app`.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi app
```

If inspecting the `/group` directory, you would find it very similar to `$ cat /etc/group | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort` :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /group
drwxrwx--- 6 root adm      4096 Aug 17 21:16 adm
drwxrwx--- 6 root audio    4096 Aug 17 21:16 audio
drwxrwx--- 6 root app      4096 Aug 17 21:16 app
..etc
```

Each directory would correspond with each group on the system.  Each group's directory is owned by that group and the system root user.

Now other users of the `app` group would have a specific location to share files with other members of that group.  A hypothetical example would allow for the `pi` user's main application to create a sql database in `/group/app` and other members of the `app` group could access it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there no /group/«groupname» directory?

Because nothing has made them.

> Would it be beneficial to have a directory structure analogous to `/home/<username>` for groups?

Maybe: There are many groups that should not be included (this is the same for users).

If you find it useful, then create them.